# How to refer to one of the column inside a SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some rows in an SQL table.
I have attributes as: id, name, etc.
Some of the names (in the name column) are built from some name ("xyz") and the id

```
id               name
333            regularName
555           somename.555  
666           myName.666
```

I want to select only rows that don't include the id inside the name.

So my query was:

```
select * 
from MY_TABLE 
where name not like '%.id'
```

But it refer to id as a string

Is there a way to refer to one of the columns value inside the query?

Comment: are the id's always integers ?

Comment: @trillion yes they are, but the name can has integers too. For example: name3434.555

Comment: What if a row for `id=42` contians the name `foobar.1234`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the ID into the comparison string:

```
select * 
from MY_TABLE 
where name not like concat('%.', id::text);
```

Comment: I got an exception: "column reference "id" is ambiguous". so :
select * 
from MY_TABLE 
where name not like concat('%.', MY_TABLE.id::text); just worked fine. Thanks

Comment: @HodiyaEyal: that error can only occur if you are joining multiple tables

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table
where 
not regexp_like(name, '.[0-9]+')
```

- if regex is supported you can use this